# Increment pixel by pixel over a gradient background image

Tags: css, frontend

I got an image that contains a complex gradient with different intermediate colors. `height: 1px; width:100px`

I got div blocks with a background color.

I want the background color of the div blocks to come from the gradient image.

For example : `.div50` class will have the `50th` pixel of the gradient image as background and `repeat-x` and `repeat-y`.

What is the best way to achieve this ?
Thanks !

Comment: `<div class="background_color"><div class="gradient_50"></div></div>` and the css for the gradient : `background-image:....;height:50px;` you can to place element with position relative / absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't currently seem to be a cross-browser solution to this.

w3 seems to be developing a cool solution to this problem of being unable to use "image fragments".
[They propose](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#image-fragments) cropping the image within the actual image call.
Instead of using:

```
background-image: url('swirl.png'); /* old UAs */
```

They propose:

```
background-image: image('sprites.png#xywh=10,30,60,20'); /* new UAs */
```

Due to the fact that this is still in the works, it probably isn't so useful to you...

---

If you need a solution now, use Mozilla:

```
background: -moz-image-rect(url('Image.jpg'), 0, 1, 1, 0);
```

This will get the first pixel (top left) of your image.

`-moz-image-rect` takes five values:

1. Image URL
2. Top-The distance *to begin* from the top.
3. Right-The distance *to end* from the left.

   - Designates the width.
   - Must always be larger than "Left".
4. Bottom-The distance *to end* from the top.

   - Designates the height.
   - Must always be larger than "Top".
5. Left-The distance *to begin* from the left.

---

#### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XFCsL/1/) <sub>Only viewable in Mozilla browsers</sub>

Made using this image:
[image: 1px rainbow]

-moz-image-rect(url('Image.jpg'), 10, 100, 25, 50);

Image: Image.jpg
This image will be cropped to 15px tall (starting immediately after the 10th pixel and continuing to the 25th pixel) and 50px wide (starting immediately after the 50th pixel and continuing to the 100th pixel).

---

A somewhat simple no-image-required solution, would be to use a pixel color finder, such as [instant eyedropper](http://instant-eyedropper.com/), to figure out the 100 different colors you would need to represent all of the pixels in your 1x100 image.  Using those colors, you can very easily create backgrounds that will function cross-browser.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

**HTML :**

```
<div class="background_color">
    <div class="gradient_50"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.background_color{
    background-color:#121212;
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
}

.gradient_50{
    background-color:red;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GX7qF/1/) you can put background-image for your effect